# subsampling a 2d array in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let's say I have a 2d array of length `n` like `[[1,2,3], [0.7, 1. 2.6], [9, 2, 1.4], ...]`. How would I use `tf.gather_nd` to return all of the first and third elements of the arrays. i.e. return an array of length `n` like: `[[1, 3], [0.7, 2.6], [9, 1.4], ...]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks a little bit hack but seems you could transpose the tensor, select rows (which corresponds to columns in the original tensor) and then transpose it back:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
​
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [0.7, 1., 2.6], [9, 2, 1.4]])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    val = sess.run(tf.transpose(tf.gather_nd(tf.transpose(x), [[0], [2]])))

val

#array([[ 1. ,  3. ],
#       [ 0.7,  2.6],
#       [ 9. ,  1.4]])
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `numpy style sub-sampling method` in tensorflow: `y = X[:,::2]`

```
x = np.array([[1,2,3], [0.7, 1., 2.6], [9, 2, 1.4]])
X = tf.constant(x)
Y = X[:,::2]

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
out = Y.eval()

#array([[ 1. ,  3. ],
#      [ 0.7,  2.6],
#      [ 9. ,  1.4]])
```

Comment: tf.gather_nd(a, [:, ::2]) gives invalid syntax

Comment: you dont use tf,gather_nd , you use  y = a[:, ::2]